# Using 2 "Group By" in one SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 3 tables that look like this:

**Locations**: id,name

**Events**: id,name,locationid

**Participants**: id,name,eventid

What I want is a query, that returns all locations, a count of the events linked to it and a count of the participants (indirectly) linked to a location.

This is what I'm trying, but this query returns a row for each tournament, instead of grouping it:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,count(b.id),count(c.id) FROM Locations a
LEFT JOIN Events b ON a.id=b.locationid
LEFT JOIN Participants c ON b.id=c.eventid
GROUP BY b.locationid,c.eventid
```

Comment: It's generally strange to GROUP BY something other than the (unaggregated) columns in the SELECT. For further help see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `count(distinct)` instead of `count()`.

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, count(distinct e.id), count(distinct p.id)
FROM Locations l LEFT JOIN
     Events e
     ON l.id = e.locationid LEFT JOIN
     Participants p
     ON e.id = p.eventid
GROUP BY l.id, l.name;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Could you give some insight, why you consider this the "quick and dirty" way? Is it bad performance-wise?

Comment: @snmueller89 . . . Actually, because you need `Events` to get to `Participants`, that comment isn't appropriate.